# NODE.JS - Check if there are unexpected fields in an object

Tags: javascript

I am sending an object with the user information from the client side to my server:

```
const newUserData = {
    name, 
    username,
    gender,
    avatar,
}
```

I am afraid of a "bad user", trying to hack my system modifying the client side like this:

```
const newUserData = {
    name, // I validate type and format in the server
    username,  // I validate type and format in the server
    gender,  // I validate type and format in the server
    avatar,  // I validate type and format in the server
    totalFollowers: 4022348978890, <------- Unexpected field on the server side...
    premium: true <------- Unexpected field on the server side...
}
```

Then, if I get this object in the server and update the database, the user will be famous and premium.

In the server side, I only expect the fields "name", "username", "gender", and "avatar".

How can I check in Node.js if the object "newUserData" has other unexpected fields?

Note: I am looking for a general way, as the hacker can add the fields he/she want, in the client side.

Comment: You could for instance define a [JSON schema](https://json-schema.org/) for your data and validate against it. You can define your schema with `additionalProperties: false` to prohibit additional fields.

Comment: You should do this check on the server side not on the client side as users can use other methods for sending malicious requests. Also, don't ever update the database using the data sent by users directly, always check, validate and escape the data before you actually update the database

Comment: Use server-side data validation library (e.g. [joi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/joi)) to sanitize user data.

Comment: Yeah, i am making the validations in the server side

Comment: Do not trust client side JavaScript. If you afraid of someone will set `permium:true` then before you save the data to the database, check your payment system ( or the payment table/ collection ) to validate if this user is really paid for premium or not. Same as followers, You don't just keep the number as follower count. You should record the ids of each followers. Do validations. Validation is not just this things like, `name.length > 3` or    `username != null` etc.

Answer (score 1):

whatever the user send the data by editing the api request parameters that will not make any difference on server side as long you only access and target the specific attributes. For example If i only want the username, email or password on server then obviously I'll only get those 3 values from API Request parameter without caring rest of the parameters. May be I edit the request and add 100 other parameters that will just send to the server but since you are accessing only 3 values from the request object then all others will be ignored. Don't need to implement complex logic however, you can use the following simple pseudo code logic for this.

```
const allowed_params = ['username','email','password']
foreach(param in request.params){
 if(param in allowed_params){
    //this is only that is allowed
 }else{
   //just ignore this
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can check for the keys equality:

```
function compareKeys(a, b) {
  var requiredKeys = Object.keys(a).sort();
  var receivedKeys = Object.keys(b).sort();
  return JSON.stringify(requiredKeys) === JSON.stringify(receivedKeys);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you are doing on the server side, you can do:

- explicitly destruct the request.body and pass each property to the next function (db update, etc.)
- use ORM library such as mongoose or Sequelize - they will throw away unexpected fields

Answer (score 0):

A relatively simple approach – though this comes with the obligatory caveat that this must be done on the server-side, and in concert with other defences – is as follows:

```js
// defining a function with Arrow syntax, into which two
// arguments are passed:
  // submittedObject: the Object supplied by the user,
  // permittedFields: an Array of permitted Object keys:
const expectedFieldsOnly = (submittedObject, permittedFields = []) => {
    // here we use Object.keys() to retrieve an Array of
    // the submitted Object's keys:
    const haystack = Object.keys(submittedObject),
      // we then use Array.prototype.filter() to iterate
      // through the Array of permitted Object keys:
      filtered = haystack.filter(
        // we use an anonymous Arrow function to assess
        // the keys; if the current key of the Array of
        // submitted Objects keys is not found in the
        // Array of permitted keys we retain that key
        // in the Array:
        (key) => permittedFields.indexOf(key) == -1
      );

    // here we return an Object containing
    // matchesExpectations: a property containing
    // a Boolean; true if the Object had only
    // expected keys, and false if extra keys were
    // found:
    return {
      matchesExpectations: filtered.length === 0,
    // an Array of the unexpected keys, to be used in
    // the event of Error messages being returned or
    // logged:
      unexpectedKeys: filtered,
    }

  },
  // an Array of expected keys:
  permitted = ['name', 'username', 'gender', 'avatar'],
  // 'good'/'normal' submission:
  submission1 = {
    name: "James",
    username: "justAGuy",
    gender: "m",
    avatar: "probably",
  },
  // 'bad'/'abnormal' submission:
  submission2 = {
    name: "James",
    username: "somebody",
    gender: "f",
    avatar: "maybe",
    totalFollowers: 4022348978890,
    premium: true
  }

console.log(expectedFieldsOnly(submission1, permitted));
console.log(expectedFieldsOnly(submission2, permitted));
```

References:

- [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).
- [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).
- [`Array.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).
- [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).